# What is IStreamPtr?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com

What is **"IStreamPtr"** ?

Is it something that hold "byte data" or can it be?

If so is it possible to write its content to file?

Comment: `IStream` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380034%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a smart pointer class that you got from the #import directive.  Derived from the _com_ptr_t class, a wrapper class for COM interface pointers.  IStream in this case.  Docs [are here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/417w8b3b%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Like any pointer type, writing it to a file is not possible.  Writing the *content* of the stream to file is certainly possible.

Comment: More accurately, while writing it to a file is possible, it's almost never useful.